# php if elseif custom style

Tags: php, list, styles, opencart

i trying to make shipping method with custom css style in opencart cms.

default code in this section is:

```
<tr class="highlight">
<td><?php if ($quote['code'] == $code || !$code) { ?>
  <?php $code = $quote['code']; ?>
  <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>" id="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>" checked="checked" />
  <?php } else { ?>
  <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>" id="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>" />
  <?php } ?></td>
<td><label for="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>"><?php echo $quote['title']; ?></label></td>
<td style="text-align: right;"><label for="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>"><?php echo $quote['text']; ?></label></td>
```

All ok in this code, and i get three links:
Shipping post, take own in the shop, Courier.

ok, i wanna make custom style in each link custom style.
I'm trying:

```
  <tr class="highlight">
<td><?php if ($quote['code'] == $code || !$code) { ?>
  <?php $code = $quote['code']; ?>
  <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>" id="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>" checked="checked" />
  <?php } else { ?>
  <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>" id="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>" />
  <?php } ?></td>
<td><label for="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>">
<?php $pastas = 'Shipping post'; ?>
<?php $atsiemimas = 'Courier'; ?>
<?php $vienetas = 'take own in the shop'; ?>
<?php if ($quote['title'] = $pastas) { ?>
    <font style="color:red;">1 link</font>
<?php } elseif ($quote['title'] = $atsiemimas) {?>
<font style="color:red;">2 link</font>
<?php } elseif ($quote['title'] = $vienetas) {?>
<font style="color:red;">3 link</font>
<?php }?>

</label></td>
<td style="text-align: right;"><label for="<?php echo $quote['code']; ?>"><?php echo $quote['text']; ?></label></td>
```

but i get from three differents links, three same links: 1 link, 1 link, 1 link.
Then i wanna to have: 1 link, 3 link, 3 link

Maybe i using wrong code? Please help.

Comment: your question is very confusing, try to rephrase and be a little more descriptive.

Comment: ok, i created a photos: 1. This is default: http://s1.postimage.org/3zi5ufhrz/defa.png, every link title is different, but i wanna to add to each link, different style. And i used the my code, code you can see in first post. And then i use my code, i get every link with same title: photo: http://s2.postimage.org/brg3za6h5/same.png

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php } elseif ($quote['title'] = $atsiemimas) {?>
<font style="color:red;">2 link</font>
<?php } elseif ($quote['title'] = $vienetas) {?>
```

should be:

```
<?php } elseif ($quote['title'] == $atsiemimas) {?>
<font style="color:red;">2 link</font>
<?php } elseif ($quote['title'] == $vienetas) {?>
```

You use a singe "=", so instead of comparing, you set te variable.

Comment: Same problem.. I get link 1, link 2, link 3

Comment: same thing for your first `if`.

Comment: if i ussing == in first if i didn't get links, i get blank area

Comment: ok, i created a photos: 1. This is default: http://s1.postimage.org/3zi5ufhrz/defa.png, every link title is different, but i wanna to add to each link, different style. And i used the my code, code you can see in first post. And then i use my code, i get every link with same title: photo: http://s2.postimage.org/brg3za6h5/same.png